# Libgdx ResolutionFileResolver not working properly

Tags: java, libgdx, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm trying to implement ResolutionFileResolver in my libgdx project
I've already created all the images with different resolutions and placed them in the appropriate drawable folders

I set my OrthographicCamera like this:

```
public static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 480;
public static final int VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 800;
camera = new OrthographicCamera ();
camera.setToOrtho (false, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
```

In the AssetManager I set ResolutionFileResolver in this way:

```
ResolutionFileResolver.Resolution [] resolutions = {
new ResolutionFileResolver.Resolution (180, 300, "drawable-ldpi"),
new ResolutionFileResolver.Resolution (240, 400, "drawable-mdpi"),
new ResolutionFileResolver.Resolution (360, 600, "drawable-hdpi"),
new ResolutionFileResolver.Resolution (480, 800, "drawable-xhdpi"),
new ResolutionFileResolver.Resolution (720, 1200, "drawable-xxhdpi"),
new ResolutionFileResolver.Resolution (960, 1600, "drawable-xxxhdpi")
};

ResolutionFileResolver resolver = new ResolutionFileResolver (new InternalFileHandleResolver (), resolutions);
manager = new AssetManager ();
manager.setLoader (TextureAtlas.class, new TextureAtlasLoader (resolver));
```

Through my DesktopLauncher, my project can be seen correctly: https://image.ibb.co/eC3TG7/Immagine.png

Instead on my Android device I am loaded with larger images than expected: https://preview.ibb.co/kxR9On/Whats_App_Image_2018_05_02_at_9_43_30_PM.jpg

How can I solve?